# File system that supports both Ubuntu and Mac on External HD

Tags: partitioning

Hi guys I want to format my External Hard drive and be usable in both Ubuntu and Mac OS, what file system can I use?

Answer (score 1):

- HFS
- HFS+ without journaling.
- FAT.
- Ext3 with fuse-Ext2 installed on the Mac.

[Here is a list for more operating systems and filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#OS_support).